# How to display 2D array in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter, multidimensional-array

I have 2D array:

```
    static final String[][] numbers = new String[][] {};
    numbers[0][0] = "A";
    numbers[0][1] = "b";
    numbers[0][2] = "c";

    numbers[1][0] = "d";
    numbers[1][1] = "e";
    numbers[1][2] = "f";

    numbers[2][0] = "g";
    numbers[2][1] = "h";
    numbers[2][2] = "z";

    gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

How can I put this to GridView with adapters?